# Anaconda Navigator Applications not launching apps

Tags: python, anaconda, navigator

For whatever reason, when I click on launch for any app in the Navigator, will say launching app with the status bar moving but it will eventually stop and the app never opens.  I have tried starting with administrative privileges and I have even tried uninstalling and reinstalling and then rebooting but still the apps never launch.

Comment: I'm having the same issue... ever figure anything out?

Comment: Unfortunately I never resolved it and I have given up on using it for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Debian distribution os then simply you can run following command in your shell after installing anaconda distribution.

## export PATH= YOUR_ANACONDA_INSTALLATION_FOLDER_LOCATION/bin:PATH

then run,

## anaconda-navigator

for example mine anaconda3 was installed at root/anaconda3,So i used following commands:

┌──[root@kali]─[/]

└──╼ # export PATH=/root/anaconda3/bin:PATH

┌─[root@kali]─[/]

└──╼ # anaconda-navigator

and that worked fine for me:)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem! The cause was in a corrupted registry affecting the launch of CMD.EXE (Used by Navigator to launch applications).
Solution: Empty the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun key
(It contained several occurrences of "if exist"!?)
If you used "conda init", then you will need to re-run the command.